# Unable to connect to cloud storage from instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm perfectly able to connect (using Go) to cloud storage from my local computer (using default credentials) but i just keep getting this error when i'm trying to connect to storage from instance.

googleapi: Error 403: User Rate Limit Exceeded, userRateLimitExceeded

This only happens on one project, it works just fine on all other projects.
On that project i can successfully connect to Datastore, Logging service, everything except Cloud storage.

When creating gce instance, i'm using Compute engine default service account with (Allow full access to all Cloud APIs).
Storage api is enabled.

I tried running gsutil (while being ssh to an instance) and i keep getting the same error.

I created a github issue (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/issues/269) but they are clueless.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you go to "API Manager" in the cloud console, is Google Cloud Storage enabled?

Comment: As i said already yes it is enabled. It works just fine with gcloud credentials on my local computer, but fails to work on instance. I'm starting to suspect that it's because that project is whitelisted for certain cloud insiders projects :/), because it works on other projects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Manager along with enabling/disabling api allows setting max quota (total and per second)..
Make sure these are > 0.

I had "requests per 100 seconds per user" set to 0.

Link to storage api:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/storage_api/quotas